# Finding characteristics of age etc using SPSS

Tags: statistics, spss

I am a beginner when it comes to SPSS, and I am not certain if when you need to discover the characteristics of individuals participating in the survey using SPSS should you do Pie charts, histograms and other graphs for age, gender etc and also find the mode, median, mean and standard deviation? Or is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

*This isn't a technical question, but a statistical one. So next time you'd better ask a question like this on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).*

To choose the appropriate types of graphs and statistical values you must first determine the measurement level of your variables. See: [Levels of Measurement on www.socialresearchmethods.net](http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/measlevl.php)

Age and income for instance are *ratio/scale* level variables, so a histogram would be an appropriate graph and mean and standard deviation would be good characteristic values.

Religion on the other hand is a *nominal* variable, where the "mean" of this variable would be meaningless. In this case "mode" would be an appropriate characteristic value (it will only tell you which is most common Religion within your survey participants, though). A pie chart would be a meaningful graph here.